# Let it know, let it knows

Tags: word-choice, verbs

I have this sentence:

> The world knows how you feel.

You can change *the world* with *it*: *It knows how you feel.*

So it is right, because if you use *The world know how you feel.* and then you replace with *it*: *It know how you feel.*

But what about this one:

> Let the world know how you feel

or

> Let the world knows how you feel.

Should it be *let it knows* or *let it know*? Why, is that a third person?

Comment: "The world know how you feel" is wrong. It should be "knows".

Comment: @Catija Is this rule applied for all collective nouns? I've seen sentences like *The police **have/has** arrested the thieves.*

Comment: @Ustanak There are many topics on ELL and ELU about "the police" and how it's a special case. "Have" is correct when referring to the police.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's *let the world know how you feel.*

It's just because *let* is followed by the base form of the verb. (AKA infinitive without *to*.)

> *Let him know*,
>   *Let them know*,
>   <s>*Let him/them knows.*</s>

Comment: Yes. It's the same as ***allow, permit***. Except unlike ***let***, those verbs require the explicit infinitive marker ***to*** (which sounds "archaic" to me in *He let me to know it was true*, but for all I know that form was *never* "valid").